# Swift how to Netflix stop app recording, in plist Restrictions for app recording

Tags: swift, restriction

Swift how to [image: Netflix] stop app recording, in .plist Restrictions for app recording, when I am trying to record the app that time I am getting the message, here I attach image please check.
same popup I want to my app

Comment: I don't know but i think this dialog show because you are using screen mirroring, i can see DockConnector here

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Camera, Mic & other hardware access that you have to declare  them in your's Info.plist file, the screen recording doesn't work that way.

You have to listen of the `UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification` notification and then you have to implement the behaviour of your app based on your needs (like present a info pop up)

In order to understand Apple's implementation I suggest you to read this kind of outdated but to the point documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017687

In addition I would follow this guide: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-at-ios-14-1f01173c31c0.

Cheers.